# What is wrong in this function?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-construction, malloc, goto

I guess there is problem with the relation of malloc and goto. Or, I guess there is some wastage of memory or corruption of memory happening out here.  Hope, someone can point to me the exact error.
When I compile its not giving me any error, but, my senior is insisting that I have a mistake.

```
#define FINISH() goto fini;

BOOL Do()
{

    BOOL stat;
    UINT32 ptr;
    int err;

    ptr = (UINT32)malloc(1000);


    free((void*)ptr);

fini:
    return stat;
}
```

Comment: `#define FINISH() goto fini;` oh lord have mercy

Comment: Please don't use `goto`.  Please don't hide `goto` inside a macro.

Comment: Does this code compile? I think not.

Comment: Why its given a -1, it is very good point for the people who don't know how to use the type-casting with pointers or people who are beginners.

Comment: I'd -1 the dogmatic `goto` bashers if I could.  `goto` has its place in C (not C++) development, and can be used to implement elegant error handling.  If you disagree please stop using your operating system, chances are it is littered with millions of `goto`s.

Comment: Is this an entry to the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/)?

Comment: Wow, this question is so heavily edited now, I'd post an answer telling you that `stat` is an undefined return value for `Do()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the problems I spotted in the code

- When `err != ERROR_SUCCESS` this function will leak memory.  It will jump over the `free` call.
- You are storing the return of `malloc` into a 32 bit location.  This is not a portable solution.  On 64 bit platforms this will wreak havoc on your program as you'd be truncating the address.  If you must use a non-pointer type here use `size_t` instead (although I would reccomend a pointer over an integral type)
- The local `stat` is not definitively assigned here.  You are returning garbage if `err != ERROR_SUCCESS`.  It needs to always be assigned a value.  Easiest way is provide a default.
- You don't check the return value of `malloc` and potentially pass a hidden `NULL` pointer into `Fun2`

Here's the function with the edits I suggested

```
BOOL Do()
{

    BOOL stat = FALSE;
    size_t ptr = 0;
    int err;

    ptr = (UINT32)malloc(1000);
    err = Fun1();

    if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS || ptr == 0)
        FINISH();
    else
        stat = Fun2(ptr);

fini:
    free((void*)ptr);
    return stat;
}
```

Comment: I think `stat` is also not initialized in case the `if` evaluates to true.

Comment: you don't need the `ptr != 0` check: `0` converts to a null pointer, and `free()` is null pointer safe

Comment: @Christoph if `Fun2(ptr)` expects a pointer to a valid object the `ptr != NULL` would be required, in any case I would advise to keep the check.

Comment: @ouah the check Christoph was referring to was for the `free` call. You are write about it incorrectly going to `Fun2` though.  I updated my answer

Comment: @JaredPar ah ok ;) yes I was considering `malloc` returns value.

Comment: `size_t` is not the correct type for a pointer to integer cast. If there is one (which might not be the case) it will be accessible through `uintptr_t`.

Comment: You were thoughtful enough to provide some suggestions but curiously enough left in a cast from `void *` to `UINT32`...  Hmmm....

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` returns a pointer. You are casting a pointer to an integer but pointers and integers are not required to have the same representation. For example the pointer size could be 64-bit and would not fit in your integer.

Also the object `stat` can be used not-initialized in your function. Without an explicit initialized the object `stat` has an indeterminate value after its declaration.

Comment: This is a correct answer. Downvoter would care for an explanation?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill, what do you think that `(UINT32)malloc(1000)` is doing?

Comment: My bad, downvote reversed, comment removed. There are so many other problems this one didn't pop out at me.

Answer (score 1):

We have no idea what this is supposed to do, but if `Fun1()` doesn't return `ERROR_SUCCESS`, then `ptr` is never freed. Presumably, that's the error your boss is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting a pointer to an `uint32_t` and back again. This erases the upper half of your pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you are not compiling that code. It has a syntax error.

```
if(foo)
  bar;;
else
  baz
```

Check your build system.

Answer (score 0):

My overall comment, and a general rule of thumb for working in C... If you have to do pointer casts, ask yourself: do you really have to?  The times you will honestly need to do pointer casts are exceedingly rare.  What's much more common is when people use pointer casts because they have some gap in understanding, don't have it very clear what they're trying to do or should be doing, and are trying to silence a compiler warning.

```
ptr = (UINT32)malloc(1000);
```

Very bad!  If you do anything with this "pointer", you will be very lucky if it works on 64-bit plaforms.  Leave pointers as pointer types.  If you absolutely must store them in an integer, use `uintptr_t` which is guaranteed to be large enough.

I'd say you might have been trying to do:

```
// Allocate 1,000 32-bit integers
UINT32 *ptr = (UINT32*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(UINT32));
```

However even that is poor form for C code, a weird C and C++ hybrid.  Unlike C++, in C you can just take a `void *` and implicitly bring it to any pointer type:

```
// Allocate 1,000 32-bit integers
UINT32 *ptr = malloc(1000 * sizeof(UINT32));
```

Lastly,

```
free((void*)ptr);
```

Casting to `void*` is another big red flag, frequently a sign that the author doesn't know what they're doing.  Once you change `ptr` to be an actual pointer type, just do this:

```
free(ptr);
```